# Jenkins: Echo command adding a space

Tags: jenkins

I have the following script in Jenkins:

```
echo "" >> ${file}
echo "T|${comment}" >> ${file}
```

But for some odd reason, Jenkins is adding a space after the comment.  You can see it after the word 'comment'.  Here is the output:

```
echo ''
echo 'T|awesomecomment '
```

Jenkins: Echo command adding a space

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure `${comment}` hasn't already got a space at the end?

Comment: yes, i checked the value for 'comment' and there were no spaces at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The space you're getting comes from your own commandline, after the `"` and before the redirection `>>`. Put the redirection to the file at the beginning of the command line like this

```
>> ${file} echo "T|${comment}"
```

See Raymond Chen's post on IO redirection ["The redirection can come anywhere on the line, and you can use that to get rid of the spaces"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170801-00/?p=96725) for why that space appears and why putting the redirection first fixes it.

Comment: i've tried doing that but i'm still getting the same results.  i read the article to gain more insight but still seeing that extra space.

Comment: Does Jenkins use DOS/Wndows batch language? Because I believe that's what that Microsoft article is talking about. If it's a Unix shell, a simple `echo "whatever" >> $file` almost certainly won't be causing a trailing space.